# How to change column data in a Bootstrap Table column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I changed the **text** of a column in my Bootstrap Table through jQuery:

`$('#my_td').text('45,999.54$');`

When I get the row object through

```
var table_data = $('#my_table').bootstrapTable('getSelections');
console.log(table_data);
```

The last column has the old value. See screenshot. The left red square is the value I get through `getSelections` and the right red square is the value I changed through jQuery.

[image: Table screenshot]

What is the right way to change the last column value and get that same value when using `getSelections`?

**Answer exemple**

This worked

```
$('#listing-employees-massive').bootstrapTable('updateRow', {index: row_index, row: {
    identifier:value
}});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the updateRow method in order to update the row info